# Получить локальную дату пользователя  из браузера в Django

Tags: python, django

Как получить локальную дату пользователя из браузера в Django, чтобы каждому пользователю отдавать контент с его тайм зоной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/ - eng
http://djbook.ru/rel1.4/topics/i18n/timezones.html - ru